# How can you override the setting of x and y properties for the purpose of dragging components in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, drag-and-drop, flex4

I have a Spark Group type called PaneledVideoPod, and I'm trying to make these things draggable - with restrictions.  Namely I don't want the user being able to partially drag these things off the screen.  What I've been noticing while implementing pretty much any part of the dragging functionality is that Flex does not handle this stuff well in general...but I don't want to digress too much on that.

One of the awkward things about Flex's implementation is that the x and y properties of that group are being changed while it's being drug, but when I try to override the setters for x and y, nothing happens:

```
override public function set x(value:Number):void
{
    Alert.show("spam"); // x is still set just fine from the dragging, and no
                        // Alert message is shown.
}
```

Trying to respond to move events isn't working until stopDrag() is called (I'm using startDrag() and stopDrag()).  I don't want to be handling this through a timer for multiple reasons.

If I can't just override the setters for x and y directly for the purposes of dragging through startDrag() and stopDrag(), what can I use to **reliably and immediately** keep x and y from being set outside of a certain range?  I've been going through some trial and error, but anything I've found has issues with either reliability, timing, or both.  Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you override the getter as well?

Comment: Have you tried passing in a bounds rectangle (the second parameter to startDrag)?

Comment: Thanks, Donald, that's working.  Turn it into an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the optional second parameter to startDrag(), a Rectangle specifying bounds to constrain the dragging of the component.